Can't create objects on start
I created a function and want to run it automatically on start. The function creates several objects
I have an error AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
Reason is clear - the function imports objects from another application (parser_app)
I am starting app like this  gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 core_app.wsgi
# project/core_app/wsgi.py

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.core.management import call_command
from scripts.create_schedules import create_cron_templates

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core_app.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
call_command("migrate")
call_command("collectstatic", interactive=False)
create_cron_templates()

Full error:
django_1         |   File "/project/core_app/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
django_1         |     from scripts.create_schedules import create_cron_templates
django_1         |   File "/project/scripts/create_schedules.py", line 1, in <module>
django_1         |     from parser_app.models import Schedule
django_1         |   File "/project/parser_app/models.py", line 7, in <module>
django_1         |     class TimeBase(models.Model):
django_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 127, in __new__
django_1         |     app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
django_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
django_1         |     self.check_apps_ready()
django_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
django_1         |     raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django_1         | django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Code of the function
# project/scripts/create_schedules.py

from parser_app.models import Schedule


def create_cron_templates():
    Schedule.objects.get_or_create(
        name="1",
        cron="0 9-18/3 * * 1-5#0 19-23/2,0-8/2 * * 1-5#0 */5 * * 6-7"
    )


Why not put the code in a regular function and call it pythonically from within wsgi.py?

AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

It does not make much sense to run makemigrations in the wsgi, you should only run makemigrations when developing the Django app, not generate these when running the app: migrations can have undesired effects, might prompt the user to check if a field was renamed, and finally, your production and dev enviornment now have different migrations.

It does not make sense to run migrate and collectstatic in wsgi as well. These are steps that should be run separately before starting your app. The WSGI server is not meant to do those things!

Solved with help of ready() function in apps.py
My solution
class ParserAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'parser_app'

    def ready(self):
        from scripts.create_schedules import create_cron_templates

        create_cron_templates()


This solution isn't great, if you ever do a fresh deployment where you don't already have the migrations run you'll see that this causes you to get errors there. Ideally that create_cron_templates should be run in a management command and that management command shouldn't be run inside the WSGI server but rather run separately before starting the WSGI server.

@AbdulAzizBarkat could you please provide a better solution?

I did mention what you should be doing in my previous comment. Don't try to make the WSGI script do more than it should be doing. That create_cron_templates is setting up some prerequisites for your application. The WSGI script / server shouldn't be responsible for those.

Incorrect syntax, see below for correction:
call_command("create_schedules", "parser_app/management/commands/schedule_fixtures.json")

Simpler still would be to not have the code as a management command:
# create_schedules.py

def create_schedules(file_path):
   ...

# wsgi.py

import create_schedules as cs

[...]
cs.create_schedules("parser_app/management/commands/schedule_fixtures.json")


I have an error:
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

Try putting the code you're trying to execute somewhere that isn't a Django app
